# Помогите разобраться с рекурсией в паскале

Tags: математика, pascal

```
function f(n: integer): integer;
begin
  if n=0 then f:=1 else f:=f(n-1)*n;
end;

begin
  write(f(5));
end.
```

Я начал изучать изучать функции и наткнулся на рекурсию, можете объяснить как рекурсия вычисялет факториал числа 5? А именно как функция разворачивает рекурсию ? Я понимаю что n будет уменьшатся от 5 до 1, но как потом эти числа умножаться друг на друга, не понимаю зачем тут нужна n!

Comment: 1. операция умножения в паскале — `*`. в приведённом вами коде она участвует всего один раз. сложно не заметить и сложно промахнуться. 2. в переменной n как раз и содержится число, факториал которого вычисляется.

Comment: в каждом учебнике рекурсия в 95% случаев разбирается именно на примере с факториалов. Что вам осталось непонятно, после прочтения учебника или хотя бы статьи в интернете?

Comment: Для информации: "в каждом учебнике рекурсия в 95% случаев разбирается именно на примере с факториалов" - хотя это как раз тот случай, когда можно обойтись без рекурсии. В определённых случаях рекурсия помогает упростить алгоритм, но злоупотряблять ею не нужно, так как она несколько замедляет выполнение и расходует память стека.

Answer (score 2):

Функция вызывается 6 раз, так что можно считать, что существует 6 копий функции, в каждой из них своё значение n: 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0 соответственно.

На первом уровне `n=5`, и вызываем `f(4)`, при этом в данной копии **хранится значение** `n=5`

На втором уровне `n=4`, и вызываем `f(3)`, при этом в данной копии **хранится значение** `n=4`

...

На последнем уровне рекурсии значение n равно нулю, функция возвращает единицу.

На предыдущем уровне получаем `f(0)=1` и умножаем на хранящееся на этом уровне значение n=1, получая опять единицу.

На предыдущем уровне получаем `f(1)=1` и умножаем на хранящееся на этом уровне значение n=2, получая результат 2.

Важно - локальные переменные функции сохраняются до возврата в нее из рекурсии.

Так продолжается до верхнего уровня, где получаем `f(4)*5=24*5=120` а это значение 5! (факториал)

Всё это вы можете легко посмотреть в отладчике, пройдя код по шагам с заходом в функцию (F7 в TP/Delphi), включив отображение нужных переменных в Watch List

Comment: @Lic Что-то осталось непонятным?